# How to split Magento order for downloadable and physical product

Tags: magento-1.7

How i can split an order into two different part (one for downloadable and second for physical) and authorize the total amount at once and capture the downloadable product amount at the time of order and for physical capture it manually from admin panel while product is ready for shipment.

Can anybody help me.............

Thanks in Advance :D

Comment: Hello experts, any help on this will definitely appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom event in `OnePageController` (if you are using Onepage checkout) under `saveOrderAction()` method.

and use the below code to remove the item from current cart and create a new order for physical product.

```
class CompanyName_ModuleName_Model_Order extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

public function createOrder() {

    $quoteID = Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->getQuote()->getId();
    $quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote")->load($quoteID);

    foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
        $itemId = $item->getId();
        $productId = $item->getProductId();
        if(put your condition here){
            /* remove the item fro which need to split the order */
            $quote->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        }
    }

    $id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);

    $transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
    $storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
    $reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('order')->fetchNewIncrementId($storeId);

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                    ->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->setQuoteId(0)
                    ->setGlobal_currency_code('USD')
                    ->setBase_currency_code('USD')
                    ->setStore_currency_code('USD')
                    ->setOrder_currency_code('USD');

    /* set Customer data */
    $order->setCustomer_email($customer->getEmail())
            ->setCustomerFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
            ->setCustomerLastname($customer->getLastname())
            ->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
            ->setCustomer_is_guest(0)
            ->setCustomer($customer);

    /* set Billing Address */
    $billing = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
    $billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING)
                    ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                    ->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultBilling())
                    ->setCustomer_address_id($billing->getEntityId())
                    ->setPrefix($billing->getPrefix())
                    ->setFirstname($billing->getFirstname())
                    ->setMiddlename($billing->getMiddlename())
                    ->setLastname($billing->getLastname())
                    ->setSuffix($billing->getSuffix())
                    ->setCompany($billing->getCompany())
                    ->setStreet($billing->getStreet())
                    ->setCity($billing->getCity())
                    ->setCountry_id($billing->getCountryId())
                    ->setRegion($billing->getRegion())
                    ->setRegion_id($billing->getRegionId())
                    ->setPostcode($billing->getPostcode())
                    ->setTelephone($billing->getTelephone())
                    ->setFax($billing->getFax());
    $order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

    $shipping = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
                    ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                    ->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultShipping())
                    ->setCustomer_address_id($shipping->getEntityId())
                    ->setPrefix($shipping->getPrefix())
                    ->setFirstname($shipping->getFirstname())
                    ->setMiddlename($shipping->getMiddlename())
                    ->setLastname($shipping->getLastname())
                    ->setSuffix($shipping->getSuffix())
                    ->setCompany($shipping->getCompany())
                    ->setStreet($shipping->getStreet())
                    ->setCity($shipping->getCity())
                    ->setCountry_id($shipping->getCountryId())
                    ->setRegion($shipping->getRegion())
                    ->setRegion_id($shipping->getRegionId())
                    ->setPostcode($shipping->getPostcode())
                    ->setTelephone($shipping->getTelephone())
                    ->setFax($shipping->getFax());

    $order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
            ->setShipping_method('freeshipping')
            ->setShippingDescription('Free Shipping - Free');
    /*set payment details here for example */
    $orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
                    ->setMethod('cybersource_soap')
                    ->setCcType('VI')
                    ->setCcNumber('4111111111111111')
                    ->setCcLast4('1111')
                    ->setCcExpMonth('2')
                    ->setCcExpYear('2013')
                    ->setCcCid('123');
    $order->setPayment($orderPayment);

    /* let say, we have 2 products */
    $subTotal = 0;
    /* pass the product id and quantity here e.g. */
    $products = array(
    '2' => array(
    'qty' => 1
    )
    );
    foreach ($products as $productId => $product) {
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $rowTotal = $_product->getPrice() * $product['qty'];
        $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
                        ->setStoreId($storeId)
                        ->setQuoteItemId(0)
                        ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
                        ->setProductId($productId)
                        ->setProductType($_product->getTypeId())
                        ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
                        ->setTotalQtyOrdered($product['qty'])
                        ->setQtyOrdered($product['qty'])
                        ->setName($_product->getName())
                        ->setSku($_product->getSku())
                        ->setPrice($_product->getPrice())
                        ->setBasePrice($_product->getPrice())
                        ->setOriginalPrice($_product->getPrice())
                        ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
                        ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);

        $subTotal += $rowTotal;
        $order->addItem($orderItem);
    }

    $order->setSubtotal($subTotal)
            ->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal)
            ->setGrandTotal($subTotal)
            ->setBaseGrandTotal($subTotal);

    $transaction->addObject($order);
    $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'place'));
    $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'save'));
    $transaction->save();
}

}
```

and don't forget to modify this code according your configuration etc.